# How to express hyperparameter distributions in Spearmint?

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameters

I'm trying to use [Spearmint](https://github.com/HIPS/Spearmint), the Bayesian optimization library, to tune hyperparameters for a machine learning classifier. My question is how does one express parameter search spaces that does not follow a uniform distribution?

From the [project's github page](https://github.com/HIPS/Spearmint/blob/master/examples/constrained/config.json), here is an example of how to set two uniformly distributed parameter search spaces:

```
"variables": {
    "X": {
        "type": "FLOAT",
        "size": 1,
        "min":  -5,
        "max":  10
    },
    "Y": {
        "type": "FLOAT",
        "size": 1,
        "min":  0,
        "max":  15
    }
}
```

How would we define a search space like the one below in Spearmint?

```
SVC_PARAMS = [
    {
        "bounds": {
            "max": 10.0,
            "min": 0.01,
        },
        "name": "C",
        "type": "double",
        "transformation": "log",
    },
    {
        "bounds": {
            "max": 1.0,
            "min": 0.0001,
        },
        "name": "gamma",
        "type": "double",
        "transformation": "log",
    },
    {
        "type": "categorical",
        "name": "kernel",
        "categorical_values": [
            {"name": "rbf"},
            {"name": "poly"},
            {"name": "sigmoid"},
        ],
    },
]
```

Is there a place to look up all of the stochastic expressions (ie `uniform`, `normal`, `log` etc) currently being supported by Spearmint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spearmint learns these kinds of transformations automatically from the data.  If you take a look here: https://github.com/HIPS/Spearmint/tree/master/spearmint/transformations
you can see the implementation of the beta warping that is applied (detailed in this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0929).  Spearmint doesn't have a way to specify these a-priori, but you could have Spearmint operate on e.g. the log of the parameters (by giving the log of the parameter ranges and exponentiating on your end).